# Quiero unir 3 tablas con una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde requiero inicio de Sesión para 3 tipos de usuario, por lo que creé una tabla en MySQL para cada tipo de usuario: uno para Admin, otro para Gobierno y finalmente uno para productor. En sus tablas cada uno requiere sus propios campos y por eso están separados; lo que quiero es juntar esas 3 tablas en una sola tabla o consulta porque después quiero consultar si el usuario (en este caso el correo) ya existe y evitar que se repitan sin importar el tipo de usuario. (Por si no queda claro, quiero la lista de todos los correos existentes sin importar el tipo de usuario pero no encuentro la forma, si sea un join o que pueda faltarme. Creé una tabla llamada `info_correo`, más adelante comento por qué).

Estas son mis tablas:

Como nota importante la llave primaria de las tablas es auto_incremental

**CORREO ADMIN**
IdCorreo_Admin AUTO_INCREMENT,
CorreoAdmin,
Nombre Completo,
Departamento,
TelefonoContacto,
Contra_admin,
ContraAdmin_Repeat,
NivelPermisoA

**CORREO PRODUCTOR**
IdCorreo_Prod AUTO_INCREMENT,
CorreoProd,
NombreUP,
Puesto_cargo,
Escolaridad,
TiempoTrabajando,
Telefono,
CodigoPostal,
Contra_Prod,
ContraProd_Repeat,
Nivel_PermisoP

**CORREO GUBERNAMENTAL**
IdCorreo_Gob AUTO_INCREMENT,
CorreoGuber,
NombreGuber,
RFC,
InstanciaGuber,
TelefonoGuber,
Contra_Guber,
ContraGuber_Repeat,
NivelPermisoG

Había creado una cuarta tabla (`info_correo`), que juntara la información de las otras 3 y con algún JOIN, pero pues no me funcionó porque si se dan cuenta esta está vacía.

**INFO CORREO**
Idcorreos
IdCorreoAdmin
IdCorreoGuber
IdCorreoProd

Aún así ya hice la consulta la cual funciona perfectamente, pero como dije, el resultado es que sale vacío.

```
SELECT * FROM `info_correo` 
INNER JOIN corr_admin ON info_correo.IdCorreoAdmin=corr_admin.IdCorreo_Admin 
INNER JOIN corr_gubernamental ON info_correo.IdCorreoGuber= corr_gubernamental.IdCorreo_Gob 
INNER JOIN corr_productor ON info_correo.IdCorreoProd=corr_productor.IdCorreo_Prod
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola edgar, puedes decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y en caso de serlo marcar como aceptada la q mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Comment: Que valores guardas en la tabla infocorreo? Los correos o los ids ??? Podes mostrar un registro ?

Comment: Hola Patrick, realmente no guardaba ningún valor, porque era una tabla vacía, la cree con la intencion de que me funcionara el INNER JOIN y despues me dí cuenta que eso lo hace la tabla nivel_permisos, ya me funciono y ya deje el resultado más abajo por si qiueres leerlo

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el uso de inner join te está limitando los registros, dado que estás pidiendo implícitamente que todos los registros estén en todas las tablas.

Prueba a utilizar LEFT JOIN y deberías ver los resultados.

```
SELECT * FROM `info_correo` 
LEFT JOIN corr_admin ON info_correo.IdCorreoAdmin=corr_admin.IdCorreo_Admin 
LEFT JOIN corr_gubernamental ON info_correo.IdCorreoGuber= corr_gubernamental.IdCorreo_Gob 
LEFT JOIN corr_productor ON info_correo.IdCorreoProd=corr_productor.IdCorreo_Prod
```

Revisa la teoria de [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) y [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) para más información

Answer (score 1):

Usa el **operador de conjuntos union**:

```
select CorreoAdmin, "Tabla_Correo_Admin"
from TablaCorreoAdmin
union
select CorreoProd, "Tabla_Correo_Prod"
from TablaCorreoProd
union
select CorreoGuber, "Tabla_Correo_Gubernamental"
from TablaCorreoGubernamental
```

Como el único campo que te dice si un usuario está en la tabla es el campo **del correo**, no es necesario seleccionar todos los campos de las tablas, con seleccionar los campos correos es suficiente.

El **operador union** permite unir los registros que se seleccionan por tabla(cada **consulta select**), este operador debe cumplir con los requisitos de que cada **select debe contener la misma cantidad de campos y todos deben ser del mismo tipo**.

En la respuesta que te doy todos los **select** tienen dos campo y son del mismo tipo por lo que puede usarse, si por ejemplo el primer **select** seleccionara un solo campo y el segundo **select** dos campos no podrás usarlo.

En cada **select** te pongo un campo que te indica el nombre de la tabla, para que sepas a que tabla pertenece ese correo, este campo es opcional, perfectamente puedes quitarlo y seleccionar por cada consulta el correo solamente, te lo puse para que tuvieras mas información, pero es prescindible.

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias por sus respuestas y por motivo de querer aportar a cualquiera que tenga el mismo problema que yo , esta fue mi solución. Creo que no lo mencione pero tenia otra tabla llamada nivel_permiso donde se encuentran todas las claves primarias (como llave foranea) por lo que fue mas facil realizar las consultas desde esa tabla y la tabla info_correo deje de usarla, no tenía caso

```
SELECT nivel_permisos.NivelPermiso,nivel_permisos.DefinicionPermiso,corr_admin.CorreoAdmin,corr_admin.ContraAdmin,corr_gubernamental.CorreoGuber, corr_gubernamental.ContraGuber, corr_productor.CorreoProd,corr_productor.ContraProd FROM `nivel_permisos`
LEFT JOIN corr_admin ON nivel_permisos.NivelPermiso = corr_admin.NivelPermisoA
LEFT JOIN corr_gubernamental ON nivel_permisos.NivelPermiso = corr_gubernamental.NivelPermisoG
LEFT JOIN corr_productor ON nivel_permisos.NivelPermiso = corr_productor.NivelPermisoP
WHERE (corr_admin.CorreoAdmin ="papa@gmail.com" ||corr_gubernamental.CorreoGuber =""||corr_productor.CorreoProd ="papa@gmail.com")
AND (corr_admin.ContraAdmin="ecfea8ce65b8930beba8867811fc144beb1a2a5d" || corr_gubernamental.ContraGuber="" || corr_productor.ContraProd="")
```

Con el select o sentencia de arriba me muestra todos los datos que yo le pido(ya solo agrego los campos que deseo) y con la condición WHERE indico que quiero la contraseña y el usuario especifico que se encuentre en cualquiera de las tablas. Me costo mucho trabajo pero esa fue a la conclusión que llegúe. Les Anexo imagen de la sentencia usada en MySQL

[image: La imagen es sobre la sentencia completa]